# property: call setter in init()

Tags: python

I have a simple class like this:

```
class TestVolume:

    def __init__(self, volume: float):

        self._volume = volume * 1000
        self.volume = self._volume


    @property
    def volume(self):
        return self._volume / 1000


    @volume.setter
    def volume(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Volume must be > 0")
        self._volume = value
```

Basically, I instantiate a `TestVolume` object with a volume, which should always be a positive float.

I want the volume attribute to be a property of the class. But I also want to check the volume when the object is created. Is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: Why just don't check it in `init` function?

Comment: No particular reason. I just discovered property. To avoid repeating myself maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter is the (for the most part) the only method that needs to modify `_volume` directly. Just use the property in `__init__`; whether or not you try to catch the `ValueError` that the setter might raise is up to you.

```
def __init__(self, volume: float):
    try:
        self.volume = volume * 1000
    except ValueError:
        self.volume = 0
```

Here, `__init__` is exercising a policy of converting a negative volume to 0 when the object is created; other users of the setter can decide for themselves what to do in the event of an exception.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I should just do ```self.volume = volume * 1000``` in ```init``` and nothing else, right ?

Comment: Right; assigning to `self.volume` inside `__init__` triggers the sett, just like any other assignment to the property.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but it won't work for creation of new objects. I'm not familiar with a way of accessing @property at `__init__`. (Python 2.7) What you can do, is inserting an assert statement. It will throw an error if the user input is invalid. You can enclode this in `try.. catch` block if you want to set a default value.

```
class TestVolume:

    def __init__(self, volume: float):
        assert volume > 0
        self._volume = volume * 1000
        self.volume = self._volume
```

And the rest of your code stays the same.